# Is there react/redux like mapStateToProps way in Vue/Vuex

Tags: reactjs, vuejs2, vuex

Usual way to map state and actions in React/Redux looks something like this, so mapping functions are placed separately from component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import myAction from 'actions/request';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  /* BODY */
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    myComponentProp: state.myReducer.myReducerProp
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    myComponentPropAction: bindActionCreators(myAction, dispatch),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

The only described way to map state and actions I have found in Vue looks like this

```
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState('myReducer', {
      myComponentProp: (state) => state.myReducerProp,
    }),
    ...{
      /* aditional manipulations with this.myComponentProp */
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('myReducer', [
      'myReducerAction'
    ]),
    ...{
      myEventHandler: function() {
        /* checke conditions before action call */
        this.myReducerAction();
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Because of the number of spreading, the code looks fuzzy, so the question is:
Is there a way to move `mapState` and `mapActions` outside component like in react/redux usual approach.

Thanks for help!

Comment: This isn't really going to work using the native functional `Vue Component` I would also probably suggest that inside Vue this is actually an anti-pattern. Getters and Setters are more than efficient enough, if you really want the react/redux look for these maybe it's time to move to the Full ES6/7 Vue Component they released alongside TS.

Comment: Thanks, where i can get more info about that?

Comment: Im i right thinking that if i have created app via vue-cli and have chosen babel in wizard babel already configured properly in my project? Where i can find babel configuration to look through it? Thanks for help!

Comment: I'll quickly see if I can find the es7 github and I'll throw it as an answer

Comment: Apologies in advance, but it's not exactly the same but it's better in my opinion. hopefully my answer uncovers some things you might not have known about :-)

Comment: Thanks, li x, i'll try that

Comment: did you have any luck with vue-class-components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so along with typescript support they also added in a vue-class-component decorator which could be used to achieve what your after. The link to the repository for this can be found here but I would suggest instead creating a new project via the CLI and going from there as it was added in v3 [Vue Class Component Github Repository](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component).

```
<script>

function Getter (getterType) {
  return createDecorator((options, key) => {
    if (!options.computed) options.computed = {}
    options.computed[key] = function () {
      return this.$store.getters[getterType]
    }
  })
}

import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

    @Component({
      props: {
        propMessage: String
      }
    })
    export default class App extends Vue {
    @Getter('foo') bar
    @Setter('psu') psi

      // computed
      get computedMsg () {
        return 'computed ' + this.msg
      }

      // method
      greet () {
        alert('greeting: ' + this.msg)
      }
    }
    </script>
```

As you can see were calling in our getters and setters using a function here which is less than optimal but is closer to a succulent answer. Now in comes the vuex-class-binding package which abstracts all of those murky functions: [vuex class](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-class)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
import {
  State,
  Getter,
  Action,
  Mutation,
  namespace
} from 'vuex-class'

const someModule = namespace('path/to/module')

@Component
export class MyComp extends Vue {
  @State('foo') stateFoo
  @State(state => state.bar) stateBar
  @Getter('foo') getterFoo
  @Action('foo') actionFoo
  @Mutation('foo') mutationFoo
  @someModule.Getter('foo') moduleGetterFoo

  // If the argument is omitted, use the property name
  // for each state/getter/action/mutation type
  @State foo
  @Getter bar
  @Action baz
  @Mutation qux

  created () {
    this.stateFoo // -> store.state.foo
    this.stateBar // -> store.state.bar
    this.getterFoo // -> store.getters.foo
    this.actionFoo({ value: true }) // -> store.dispatch('foo', { value: true })
    this.mutationFoo({ value: true }) // -> store.commit('foo', { value: true })
    this.moduleGetterFoo // -> store.getters['path/to/module/foo']
  }
}
```

This is there example and it's really nice because were able to take a namespaced module and call all of it's getters and setters without any nasty custom functions and we can import all of that ready to use into a `const` like above. Now you'd have access to all of your modules functionality using just decorators. This is as close as it really gets to being able to assign your functionality into the component sadly, but it looks pretty nice once you've got it all setup. You can do this with or without TS I think but I've always done it in TS as it has the first class support for the vue class components which are still relatively new.